# COUNT by each channel using postgreSQL for the last year from today

Tags: postgresql

My table looks like the following-

[image: Order Table]

How do I find how many orders are in each channel for the last year from today in PostgresSQL?

I know how to find it for each channel by running individual queries. But there are **10** channels and it doesn't really make sense to run the query 10 times.

The query that I used to run it for one channel -

```
SELECT COUNT(order) FROM order_table WHERE channel = 1 AND date BETWEEN '2019-01-12' AND '2020-01-14';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it should just be a matter of grouping by channel:

```
SELECT channel, COUNT(order) 
FROM order_table 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2019-01-12' AND '2020-01-14'
GROUP BY channel
;
```

Comment: This should be fine